# Why do "ArrayList.remove" remove both in local variable and in myApplicationClass?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a MyApplicationClass into which I stock An ArrayList, then I create a variable ArrayList in my MainActivity and assign it the variable in MyApplciationClass and finally I call remove to the local variable to remove a value but the value is removed from both MyApplicationClass and the localvariable and it can be possible because I just retrieve the list from MyApplicationClass I didin't make anything else ?

Here is my code:

MyApplicationClass:

```
private ArrayList<String> text = new ArrayList<>();


public ArrayList<String> getText() {
    return text;
}

public void addTest(String input) {
    text.add(input);
}
```

MainActivity:

```
//When click on a button:

final MyApplicationClass myApplicationClass = (MyApplicationClass) getApplicationContext();

//I add some example values
myApplicationClass.addTest("1");
myApplicationClass.addTest("2");

//Here I retrieve the variable in MyApplicationClass to put in into a local variable:

ArrayList<String> testlocal = myApplicationClass.getText();

//And here I remove a value from the localvariable testlocal:
test.remove(1);
```

But when I debug and see variable I can see that the value is correctly deleted in *testlocal* but too in text in *MyApplicationClass* but I just want to remove a value from *textlocal*.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two variables refers to the same `ArrayList` object.

This assignment makes `testlocal` refers to the `ArrayList` object of the `MyApplicationClass` instance :

```
ArrayList<String> testlocal = myApplicationClass.getText();
```

To create a new `ArrayList`, you have to create a new object by using the `new` operator :

```
ArrayList<String> testlocal = new ArrayList<>(myApplicationClass.getText());
```

Now removing (or even adding) one element in any of these two `ArrayList` objects will never be reflected in the other `ArrayList` object.

But note that new `ArrayList(Collection c)` will not make a deep copy of the elements copied.
So modifying the state of any element in one or the other `ArrayList` object will be still reflected in the other.
In your actual case, it is not a problem as the `List`s store only `String` values that are de facto immutable.

Comment: Note that (in this case) a deep copy isn't even needed, since String is immutable in Java.

Comment: @Tobias Weimer I confess not having looking the type of the elements. Thank you for the feedback. I updated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a copy of the original list. Also, generally it's better to depend on the `List` interface instead of the `ArrayList` class.

You can create the copy in the `getText()` method. This is easy because you need to modify the code on only one place. On the other hand, no outer class will be able to change your `MyApplicationClass`:

```
public List<String> getText() {
    return new ArrayList<>(text);
}
```

Alternatively, you can create a local copy whenever you retrieve it:

```
List<String> testlocal = new ArrayList<>(myApplicationClass.getText());
```